# Get last key from jsonb (postgres)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Considering the following content on a jsonb field, and that the keys immediately after "audio" are random (I'll never know which value it'll be returning beforehand): is there any way I can query for the last key inside "audio" ("2814462280" in this example)?

```
   {
        "test": {
            "audio": {
                "1175828715": {
                    "direction": "outbound",
                },
                "2814462280": {
                    "direction": "inbound",
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2814462280 is the last one because 2814462280 > 1175828715?

Comment: Can't you select them by inbound or outbound?

Comment: @lemon theoretically yes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no

Comment: If that really is a jsonb column, then "the last key" is meaningless, as Postgres will re-order the keys in the JSON value. So the order you put in, is not the order in which it is stored.

Comment: ok, but I still want to get it :) Imagine that I have a "metadata" jsonb column, and I want to query the value under the last key of "audio" from all the records I have. I want to know if there's a way to build this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote a function to dynamically construct jsonb path to get the last key value.

As was previously mentioned in the comments section Postgres can reorder the keys in a jsonb field.

Here is the [demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3ywwt8n2p).

```
do $$
declare
  -- instantiate all the necessary variables
  audio_json jsonb;
  audio_json_keys text[];
  last_key_index integer;
  last_key_pointer text;
  result_json jsonb;
  query text;
  
begin 

audio_json := (select (metadata->>'test')::jsonb->>'audio' from test);
audio_json_keys := (select array_agg(keys) from jsonb_object_keys(audio_json::jsonb) keys);
last_key_index := (select array_length(audio_json_keys, 1));
last_key_pointer := audio_json_keys[last_key_index];

query := 'select (''' || audio_json::text || ''')::jsonb->>''' || last_key_pointer::text || '''';
execute query into result_json;

raise info '%', result_json;

end $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Object.keys** can be useful in this case. If you want to query for the last key. you can try following

```
const obj =    {
        "test": {
            "audio": {
                "1175828715": {
                    "direction": "outbound",
                },
                "2814462280": {
                    "direction": "inbound",
                }
            }
        }
    }

const audio_obj:any = obj.test.audio
const keys = Object.keys(audio_obj)
const len = keys.length
const lastKey: string = keys[len-1] // "2814462280"
```

if you want to get the last object you can add one line code

```
const lastObj = audio_obj[lastKey] // {"direction": "inbound"}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hey @SouLNex thanks but I'm looking for a sql solution using postgres